# Adding Image and Text to JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have added an image and text using two statements. But in JTextPane, it shows only text. My code given below -

```
jTextPane1.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("t.png"));
jTextPane1.setText("Technology Wallpaper");
```

How to add both image and text to the jtextpane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText` will replace the contents of the underlying `Document` with the text you pass it.  In order to update the text pane, you will need to append the text directly to the document

[image: Appending the text]

```
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("mySuperAwesomePictureSomewhere.jpg"));
try {
    Document doc = tp.getDocument();
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nTruer words were never spoken", null);
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
add(new JScrollPane(tp));
```

Obviously, if you want insert text before the image, it would be worth noting the current `Document` length first and the inserting your new text at that point, after you've inserted the image, depending on your needs

You may also want to take some time and have a look at [Using Text Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) to get a better understand how the text API works

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `setText` is replacing the whole document. You can use `JTextPane#getDocument().insertString()` to add text along with the ICON. Something like follows:

```
    pane.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("logo.png"));
    pane.getDocument().insertString(0, "Hello World", null);
```