# How to show ImageIcons in JTextPane only vertically, one below the other?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, imageicon

I'm getting BufferdImages from a device and converting them to ImageIcons and showing them in JTextPane.

```
public static void insertImage(BufferedImage img, JTextPane jTextPane){

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    jTextPane.insertIcon(icon);

}
```

My problem is that images are added one after another in one line and I have to scroll horizontally to see them.
I want each new ImageIcon to go below the previous one, in other words, to add a new line after each ImageIcon.

I tried doing `jTextPane.setText("\n");` after adding each image, but this only reset the whole jTextPane.

I need to show these images in a Swing application among some other data, and if someone has a better suggestion on what to use instead jTextPane for this purpose, please suggest it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to [JTextPane appending a new string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059198/jtextpane-appending-a-new-string)

Comment: Have you considered using HTML based text?

Comment: Maybe using something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232214/adding-image-and-text-to-jtextpane/52232322#52232322)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can vertically align images in a JTextPane using the underlying [StyledDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html). With this document, you can manually add line breaks at a position of your choice.

```
BufferedImage img1 = ...
BufferedImage img2 = ...

// add first image
jTextPane.insertIcon(img1);

// add line break at the end
StyledDocument doc = jTextPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n" , null);

// add second image
jTextPane.insertIcon(img2);
```

Comment: Thanks, both yours and the comment/example from @MadProgrammer helped me to get the wanted result.